# Version of exe online

Tags: c#, version, exe

Can you help me please in C# ?

```
var versionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo("http://dl2.itools.hk/dl/itools3_en/iToolsProSetup_EN_3.3.0.6.exe");
string version = versionInfo.ProductVersion;
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Can you provide us more information about your problem or issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to download the file first. If you don't need the file besides checking for the version, you can download it to a temporary file, check the version and delete it.

Just a quick example:

```
var tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadFile("http://url/to/file.exe", tempFile);
var versionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(tempFile);
string version = versionInfo.ProductVersion;
File.Delete(tempFile);
```

Note however, the file on the URL in your post doesn't have the version information in it, so the ProductVersion returned would be null.

Comment: Thank you for your help.